# Able to mock but gets exception as int type object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

```
  @patch("dao.qualcomm_transaction_service.QualcommTransactionService.get_max_qualcomm_id",20) 
def test_lambda_handler(): 
lambda_handler(event, None)
```

I used mocking seeing your example and my method expects to return 20 whenever in lambda function testing locally get_max_qualcomm_id us made .but on reaching the above method i get a exception int type object is not Callable. Please let me know what is the problem here .

This is actual method being call which i am trying to mock which is called withing lambda function(testing lambda locally):

```
last_max_id = QualcommTransactionService().get_max_qualcomm_id(self.subscriber_id)
```

My folder strcuture is like this  :

```
functions
  -subscription_lambda
     -qt_lambda_event.py
layers
  -subscription-service
     -python
       -soap
          -qt
             -qualcomm-transaction-main.py
       -config
   -data-access-layer
      -python
        -dao
          -qualcomm_transaction-service.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question all i had to was instead passing 20 in the path i returned Mock() object and  returned value as 20

```
maxidMock = Mock()
maxidMock.return_value = 20

      @patch("dao.qualcomm_transaction_service.QualcommTransactionService.get_max_qualcomm_id",20) 
def test_lambda_handler(): 
 lambda_handler(event, None)
 maxidMock.assert_called_with(6)
```